# cannot access json github api response correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, api, github-api

I am trying to access a JSON response data from the github job posting API. Here is the JSON response structure:

```
 [
    {"id":"1", "title":"gameon"}, 
    {"id":"2", "title":"hardlife"},
    {"id":"3", "title":"lotsofbugs"}
 ]
```

I have been crazy finding solutions accessing **id** and **title**. I tried several ways like (assuming the response is stored in a JS variable named jsonResponse) this:

> **jsonResponse[0][1]["title"]**

and even something like

> **jsonResponse[1]["title"]**

but everything seems to not work at all. I want to access each **id** and **title** for every part of the response but I cannot find a way. I use to alert everything while testing it if I could access it. Everything it says is undefined whenever I try to access the JSON response data. Can someone please help me?

Comment: `jsonResponse[0].title`, `jsonResponse[0].id`, `jsonResponse[1]["title"]` is also fine.

Comment: As @dfsq says, your second example (`jsonResponse[1]['title']`) should work fine. Have you checked the console to ensure that you have no errors in your code, and that the request completes successfully?

Comment: yes @Rory McCrossan, your answer should be good, however when I check the console it says that the AJAX request successfully executed as it already returns a response. this is a bit weird though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are dealing with a javascript object if you are dealing with json data.   You really should just use *$.parseJSON()* if you can, but if not, you should be able to access the object by using `myObj.id` and `myObj.title.`   OR possibly `myObj[0].id` , `myObj[0].title` etc...  (if you need more in depth, try the javascript object reference)

Just got some updated code and a [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/incept0/qcdL3drq/) for you...   this is some code that kind of tests and demos the stringify and parseJSON functions so you can play around with it.  As you can see it's getting the correct data and alerting it. :)

```
(function($){ 
    $(function(){  //document.ready

    var myResponseData = [
        {"id":"1", "title":"gameon"}, 
        {"id":"2", "title":"hardlife"},
        {"id":"3", "title":"lotsofbugs"}
     ];
        myResponseData = JSON.stringify(myResponseData);
        console.dir(myResponseData);
        var myObj = $.parseJSON(myResponseData);
        console.dir(myObj);
        alert(myObj[0].title);    
    });     
})(jQuery);
```

Also as the other answer suggests, you can use a for each loop to iterate over the contents.   I would def `console.dir()` the response and make sure you are getting the data back correctly before ripping your hair out.  :)   Using chrome dev tools you can view the contents of the response by putting this line in your code...

```
console.dir(myResponseData);
```

You can also view the data going back and forth by clicking on "Network" in chrome dev tools, then clicking on the filename of your ajax script.   It should default to 'Response' but if not, click on that.

[image]

[image]

Please let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Hi @Notorious Pet(), thanks for the suggestions. I am using chrome debugging tool finding it out even before posting the question. I really have trouble finding a solution as I know that it should have worked already. I do not think $parse.JSON is needed since it was already returned by the API call as a JSON response already

Comment: If you want to use the JSON in your script, you should use parseJSON if you are using jquery.   http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/  It turns JSON into a javascript readable object, not the other way around.

Comment: you were right @Notorious Pet(), using the $.parseJSON of jquery helped by turning the JSON into a javascript readable object. however, my question is, isn't JSON already a javascript readable object by default?

Comment: JSON is just a string that is formatted a certain way.   I've updated my answer with a JSFIDDLE link you can play around with if you like.  Glad I could help..  :)

Answer (score 4):

If you want to access each in turn you can use the `forEach` function.

```
var response =  [
     {"id":"1", "title":"gameon"}, 
     {"id":"2", "title":"hardlife"},
     {"id":"3", "title":"lotsofbugs"}
];

response.forEach(function(obj) {   
   var id = obj.id;
   var title = obj.title;
   // Do things with the data here 
});
```

Comment: this gives me an error like:

Uncaught TypeError: response.forEach is not a function

Comment: Are you copying the code exactly as I had it?  It should work, forEach is a native function on the Array Prototype.

Comment: yes @ChadF, I copied the code exactly as you wrote it. I looked into the google chrome debugging tool console and it gives me
`Uncaught TypeError: response.forEach is not a function`

Comment: If you're running this code right when you get it, it may still be stringified.  Try `var respObj = JSON.parse(response);`

Otherwise I have no idea what is wrong on your end.  Run typeof on response and make sure it's an array.

Comment: I already figured it out. Notorious Pet() was correct, by using $.parseJSON() function of jquery i was able to turn the JSON into a javascript readable object and your code also works in looping through the array. Thanks a lot!